# How to parse a structure in a union in CPP?

Tags: c++, c, function, structure, unions

I have a union and enum, for eg:

```
typedef union{
    Home   HomeInfo;        
    Office OfficeInfo;          
} Info;

typedef enum{                               
    eHOME,  
    eOFFICE

} InfoType;
```

`Home` and `Office` are other structures.

I have another function whose prototype is

```
void SetInfo(InfoType, Info);
```

During function call, if `InfoType` is `eHOME`, I would create a object of Info, `Info info;` and fill `HomeInfo` details `info.HomeInfo` and call

```
SetInfo(eHONE, info);
```

SetInfo definition:

```
SetInfo(InfoType infotype, Info info)
{
    if (eHOME == infotype)
    {
        // get the details from info.HomeInfo structure
         }
         else if(eOFFICE == infotype)
         {
            // get the details from info.OffiiceInfo structure
         }
}
```

How can I get an invalid case if I pass `eHOME` as `InfoType` and passing the details of `OfficeInfo`? While I used to get the details of `HomeInfo` at this time, there are junk values in it, so error is not getting. Is it possible to check what the structure is after `InfoType` checking?

Comment: I read your question about three times, and I still cannot understand it... can you create a self contained simple example with expected output for some input to highlight the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but this approach is almost for sure wrong. I suggest using inheritation here:

```
enum InfoType
{
    eHome,
    eOffice,
};

class Info
{
public:
    InfoType type() const { return type_; }

protected:
    Info(InfoType t) : type_(t) {}

private:
    InfoType type_;
};

class HomeInfo : public Info
{
public:
    HomeInfo() : Info(eHome) {}
};

class OfficeInfo : public Info
{
public:
    OfficeInfo() : Info(eOffice) {}
};
```

Now `SetInfo` function is as easy as:

```
void SetInfo(Info* info)
{
    if (info->type() == eHome)
    {
        HomeInfo* hi = (HomeInfo*)info;
        // ...
    }
    else if (info->type() == eOffice)
    {
        OfficeInfo* oi = (OfficeInfo*)info;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

void SetInfo(InfoType a, Info b);

Maybe you can cast &b to a Home*, then hardcode the first "class variable" of both Home and Office to a char that you can detect and initialize with specific values for easy detection.

Does this make any sense,,,...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should ensure that Info and InfoType are consistent in every call of SetInfo.

If you intended call SetInfo with inconsistent Info and InfoType, for example:

```
InfoType type = eHOME;
Info info;
info.OfficeInfo.xxx = xxx;
SetInfo(type, info);
```

Basically, as a union, you cannot distinguish whether info is an OfficeInfo or a HomeInfo, without further information of the 2 types.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of checking is possible.  `info` is not intrinsically `Home` or `Office`.  It is a block of bytes, which you can choose to interpret as either one, because it is a union.

This does not seem like a good use for a union at all.  Instead `Office` and `Home` should inherit from a common parent, say `Info`.  Then `SetInfo` should take a reference to `Info`,
like this:

```
void SetInfo(Info &myInfo);
```

And you would need some factory method that knows whether it needs to pass in an instance of `Home` or `Office`.